# We use a debug device connected to USB but we can't get bidirectional communication

Tags: usb, hotplug

We use Totalphase Cheetah devices to program SPI parts on end-point devices, however, the Cheetah device won't communicate yielding "ERROR: Unable to find any Cheetah Adapters!  Verify that Total Phase USB drivers are installed"  Which I believe they are installed correctly in /etc/udev so what else could I have missed?  Is there a way to get the hotplug on this device to operate correctly?  When I check /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices it shows the cheetah connected on Bus03 port00 with USB high speed rating 480.  This tells me that at least Linux is able to identify the device on the USB.  How do I enable hotplug or even connecting at boot  to enable communication?
Not sure what in /dev directory "drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4900 Nov 29 08:16 dev/" the user is in the user, adm and sudo groups. –
BDANIEL
Nov 29 at 15:38
I have been doing some digging and I think this is probable as to the reason, not sure how to correct it however. There is a utility from TotalPhase called "detect.py" which looks for the specific device, in this case a Cheetah SPI Host Adapter, which shows the following: root@sys1:/home/cheetah/cheetah-api-linux-x86_64-v3.08/python# sudo python detect.py Searching for Cheetah adapters... 1 device(s) found: port = 0 (avail) (1363-899961) –
BDANIEL
Nov 29 at 15:41
Aparently folks believe the first question should be done perfectly but since I am a mere human...
The permissions for the device are -rwx-r--r-- so unless I am mistaken the user should be able to read/write and execute.  Same goes for all of the parametric files that accompany the device as well as the programming for the spi devices that are programmed with the device.
The user is in groups, adm, sudo, lpadmin.

Comment: What `group` does the `/dev/` have, and what `group` does your user have ? `ls -l /dev/` and `id`.

Comment: What are the permissions of the actual device? [Edit] your Question to reply, don't Add Comment. `ls -l /dev/chee*`, or, just after connecting the device, `ls -lrt /dev | tail`. That it "works" as `root` tells us it's a permissions problem, probably.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.